# WooCommerce JetEngine API: update meta box fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, jet-engine

I need to programmatically update Meta Box meta fields by JetEngine for WooCommerce products.I searched all over but couldn't find and clear explanation on how to update the meta fields programmatically.

[image: first picture]

As you can see in the picture below, The meta field settings have an option to enable REST API, which suggests that it *is* possible to update the fields programmatically, somehow.

[image: second picture]

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

turns out these meta fields get stored as regular metadata in the product object. So updating the fields is as simple as updating the product metadata.